# What are the benefits of rounding to tick precision

Tags: pine-script

I'm using the `close` value in the snippet below for multiple purposes.

Two examples that not related to the code below:

1. `ema = ema(close, 200)`. Is there a real benefit if I use the `rounded close` instead of the `close`? I heard that it's mostly useful in Forex.
2. `close > ema`. What about here?

What are the real benefits from the rounded tick precision?

Speaking of it, can I replace every `close`, `open`, `high`, `low` usage with its rounded version from `f_roundedToTickOHLC()`?

```
// ————— Functions rounding OHLC to tick precision
f_roundedToTickOHLC() =>
    float _op = round(open  / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick
    float _hi = round(high  / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick
    float _lo = round(low   / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick
    float _cl = round(close / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick
    [_op, _hi, _lo, _cl]

// ————— Get rounded prices
[rOpen, rHigh, rLow, rClose] = f_roundedToTickOHLC()

// ————— Pullback
ema = ema(close, i_emaPullback)

// ————— TV built-in MACD code
fastLength = 12
slowlength = 26
MACDLength = 9
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)

// ————— Filter
filterLong = MACD > 0
filterShort = MACD < 0

// ————— States
var float entryPrice = na
var bool inLong = false
var bool inShort = false
bool inTrade = inLong or inShort

// ————— Entries
enterLong  = doLongs  and not inTrade and crossover(MACD, 0)
enterShort = doShorts and not inTrade and crossunder(MACD, 0)

// ————— Stops
atr = atr(14)
stopLong  = min(lowest(5), min(close, open) - atr * 1.5)
stopShort = max(highest(5), max(close, open) + atr * 1.5)

// ————— Exits
exitLong  = inLong  and ((crossunder(MACD, aMACD) and MACD > 0) or close < stopLong[1])
exitShort = inShort and ((crossover(MACD, aMACD) and MACD < 0)  or close > stopShort[1])

if enterLong
    inLong := true
    entryPrice := close
else if enterShort
    inShort := true
    entryPrice := close
else if exitLong
    inLong := false
    entryPrice := na
else if exitShort
    inShort := false
    entryPrice := na
```